# Architecture Diagram with Animations

Tags: web-server, diagram

I'm looking for a software to design an architectural structure of a platform. There are plenty of tools for creating static diagrams, but I'm searching for a tool that is able to show the flow of information with animations.

I want to be able to show how multiple web services inter-communicate. The tool should visualize in an animated way the path of the requests. Questions like:

- who communicates with who?
- *how* is being communicated (`POST`, `GET`, message publish etc)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try https://icepanel.io. It promotes describing your architecture using the C4 model and allows for modelling as opposed to straight diagramming where there is metadata about your components. You can animate